# outputting a CSV file from shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

Hi I have an input file in this format.

```
[Header A]
key1 value1
key2 value2

[Header B]
header1    header2    header3   // separated by tab
1            2          3     //separated by tab
a            b          c     //separated by tab

[Header C]
a
b
c
```

I have to output whatever is in HeaderB as another csv file
So the CSV file will look like

```
header1,header2,header3
1,2,3
a,b,c
```

I wrote a python script to do that but the requirement it to do it via a shell command. I don't have much idea about writing complicated shell commands. Can someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you at least use [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)?

Comment: are the inline comments *actually* in the input file?

Comment: no they aren't.. I put them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
awk -F'\t' '/\[Header B\]/{f=1;next} /^$/{f=0} f{gsub(/\t/,",");print}' file
```

#### Example

```
$ awk -F'\t' '/\[Header B\]/{f=1;next} /^$/{f=0} f{gsub(/\t/,",");print}' file
header1,header2,header3
1,2,3
a,b,c
```

Comment: awesome.. thanks.. I'll read the  command carefully and understand what its doing so that I do it myself the next time.. Thanks once again.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` command.

```
sed -n '/^\[Header B]/,/^$/s/\t/,/gp' file.ini >section.csv
```

The script is straightforward; it consists of an "address" part to select lines between the header and the next empty line, and an action part to substitute tab with comma globally (all occurrences on a line) and print if a substitution was performed (so conveniently, only lines which had a tab will be printed).

If your `sed` doesn't support the `\t` escape for tab, you'll have to put in a literal tab (in some shells, you have to type ctrl-V tab on the command line).